# Adding two list in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

Can anyone help me. This is what i want to do.

`x = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
 y= [0,1]`

```
desired output = [
                 [[1,2,3,4,5],[0,1]],
                 [[6,7,8,9,10],[0,1]]
                                    ]
```

I try putting it in a for loop

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
>>> for value in x:
...     a = []
...     a += ([x,y])
...     print(a)
...
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]], [0, 1]]
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]], [0, 1]]
```

I also tried doing this

```
>>> for value in x:
...     a = []
...     a += ([x,y])
...     print(a)
...
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1]]
```

Thank you for helping. I need it for putting label on my data for neural networks.

Comment: I solved it now. i use w = [b + [[0,1]] for b in x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension, and iterate over each sublist in `x`. Since you're inserting `y` into different sublists, you might want to insert a *copy* of the list, not the original.

```
[[i, y[:]] for i in x]
```

Or,

```
[[i, y.copy()] for i in x]
```

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1]], [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1]]]
```

The copy is done as a safety precaution. To understand why, consider an example,

```
z = [[i, y] for i in x]  # inserting y (reference copy)
y[0] = 12345

print(z)
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [12345, 1]], [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [12345, 1]]] # oops
```

Modifying the original `y` or the `y` in any other sublist will reflect changes across all sublists. You can prevent that by inserting a copy instead, which is what I've done at the top.

Comment: This answer really helped me Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
   z[i] = [x[i],y];
```

Comment: Always remember to add explaination to the answer you post, so the users can understand the use of it.  @carexcer